# FFMPEG: FLV header for AVPacket

Tags: ffmpeg, flv

I used FFMPEg codes in my app, where I need to get FLV packets for my program.  For this I use avcodec_encode_video2(). My problem is that function creates AVPacket packet, which does not keep a full FLV format,  only its body. But I need still its header. Usually another function (av_write_frame()) makes it. I cannot use av_write_frame() in my app, because it does not fit my requirement. So maybe anybody knows a function in ffmpeg library, which could add FLV header to the created packets by avcodec_encode_video2().

Answer (score 0):

The FLV header by itself is relatively simple.

It can be modelized with the following code:

```
/* FLV file header */
#define FLV_SIGNATURE       "FLV"
#define FLV_VERSION         ((uint8)0x01)

#define FLV_FLAG_VIDEO      ((uint8)0x01)
#define FLV_FLAG_AUDIO      ((uint8)0x04)

typedef struct __flv_header {
    uint8_t         signature[3]; /* always "FLV" */
    uint8_t         version; /* should be 1 */
    uint8_t         flags;
    uint32_t        offset; /* always 9 */
} flv_header;
```

The `flags` field is a bitmask telling whether the file possesses video, audio, or both streams. For example, if your file has audio and video, its value will be 5.

Be careful that the `offset` field is encoded in big-endian, which on little-endian platforms is represented by the value 150994944.

If you do not wish to use such a structure, and have a way to directly write a buffer, you can create it like this:

```
uint_8 buffer[9] = {0x46, 0x4c, 0x56, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09};
```

Comment: thanks, this header is for FLV file, I need for FLV packet: Type, BodyLength, Timestamp, TimestampExtended, StreamId, Body (http://osflash.org/flv#flv_format).  There is  flv_write_packet(AVFormatContext *s, AVPacket *pkt) in ffmpeg, which creates this header

Comment: Ah sorry for the misunderstanding :) Technically, I described you the header, what you desire instead is the FLV tags.